# PHP. array_column() analogue for SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, simplexml

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[803]
public 'row' => 
array (size=13)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[797]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=4)
          'codeonimage' => string '01' (length=2)
          'name' => string 'Крышка' (length=12)
          'oem' => string '13711251885' (length=11)
          'ssd' => string '$HgsQRnNPF0d$' (length=174)
      public 'attribute' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[813]
              public '@attributes' => 
                array (size=3)
                  'key' => string 'amount' (length=6)
                  'name' => string 'Количество' (length=20)
                  'value' => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[814]
              public '@attributes' => 
                array (size=3)
                  'key' => string 'end_of_production' (length=17)
                  'name' => string 'end_of_production' (length=17)
                  'value' => string 'Не производтся с: 19871116' (length=40)
...
```

I'm trying to take all the 'oem' values from each SimpleXML element like:

```
   array_column($simpleXMLObject->row, 'oem');
```

... and of course I get an error:

```
array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
```

There is another option with a full search. But maybe there is some more pretty way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the original XML rather than a dump of the loaded data.

Comment: The column should be `@attributes` instead of oem which is a sub-key

Comment: @GrowingBrick The `@attributes` is just a notation in the `var_dump` output, it doesn't actually exist. The normal access would look something like `$something->row[0]['oem']`, where `->foo` accesses an element or collection of same-named elements, and `['foo']` accesses an attribute.